# How to get specified element from data in json result from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I've read multiple articles and questions on this, but none of the suggestions seem to be working for me. I have a json result that my ajax call returns, and I want to put each value of the result into input fields. I'm getting close, "JSON.stringify(data)" is returning my full result in my input field.. But how do I get just the "recovery" value from it?

Here's what the full data result looks like:

```
{"data":{
"id":12,
"name":"hello",
"addDt":"2020-11-06T00:00:00",
"recovery":"hello",
"latestRecovery":"hello",
"latestSituation":"hello",
"nextSteps":"hello",
"requestId":null}}
```

And here's my current ajax call:

```js
    function LoadUpdate(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "?handler=updateValuesJson&id=" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("recovery").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data); // I need "recovery" element from this string result
                $("#updatemodal").modal();
            }
        });
    }
```

What I've tried out:

- JSON.stringify(data) is the full string result (but I need the value of "recovery")
- JSON.stringify(data.recovery) is "undefined"
- JSON.stringify(data[3]) is "undefined"
- data is "[object Object]"
- data.recovery is "undefined"
- data["recovery"] is "undefined"
- JSON.parse(data)[i]['recovery'] isn't successful

I'm brand new to ajax/json - What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the object that your recieve is a JSON object that encapsulate your data object, so you need to to do the following to read the real data object that you search

```
success: function (response) 
{ 
document.getElementById("recovery").innerHTML = response.data.recovery;
 $("#updatemodal").modal(); 
}
```

Comment: Ha, this made it click for me! Response and data are two separate objects, I see. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if `resp` is the response object, you'd need to select the `data` object inside like so:

```
const name = resp.data.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

in success function first check data with `console.log()`

```
...
success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
```

if show data in console was wrong you should check your response and backend Code.